# HTTP Basic auth issue

Tags: python

Doc: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueidorkey-get-example

API: `https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/comment`

python script:

```
url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

Error

[image]

Update1

```
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Update2

Install `requests` then get another issue, please check the pic.
And I try to install `json` via `python -m pip install json` but cannot do this.
[image]

Comment: Use `requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth`.

Comment: Same issue: `NameError: name 'requests' is not defined`

Comment: Is requests installed on your system? If not, install it first.

Comment: Got it, I need to search some doc to install the package requests

Comment: You can see this: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#python-m-pip-install-requests

Comment: I tried to install requests via pip and it works, then I run the script and get the same issue...

Comment: You should follow the posted answer to correctly import the required HTTPBasicAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing an import statement.

at the top of the script try adding:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but not work, please check the update1

Comment: @VitoLiu
it means you need to download the `requests` package. you can do it using `pip`.
if you already downloaded it, make sure it's downloaded to the interpreter/virtual environment that you're currently trying to run.

Comment: I do not know how to do this, i need to search some doc to using `pip`

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/pip/ and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/
good luck :)
either way, you should mark this answer as correct, since it solved the issue described in the question.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Please check the update2... I believe that it is the last issue in this error

Comment: @VitoLiu you're right, you also had use in the `json` package which you should also download and import. added the answer
opposed to `requests`, the `json` package is builtin package, so you don't have to download/install it.

Comment: Thx for your help